# Expectation of semi-orthogonal random projection

Tags: expected-value, orthogonal-matrices

Suppose I want to compute the expectation of $\|x'O\|_2$ where $O$ is a random matrix having the uniform distribution on the set of $n \times r$ $(r \leq n)$ semi-orthogonal matrices (i.e., $O'O = I_r$.); $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is fixed.

My intuition tells me that, ${\rm E}(\|x'O\|_2) = \sqrt{\frac{r}{n}}\|x\|_2$ (where the expectation is taken wrt the distribution for $O$) but I'm having a difficult time proving this. How would I go about this? Are there any references I am missing?

Comment: Is $x$ also random, or is it a constant?

Comment: It is fixed -- updated my question to make this clear. Thanks!

Comment: It's known that you can generate matrices $O$ by using $O=Q(Q^{T}Q)^{-1/2}$ where the entries of the $n$ by $r$ matrix $Q$ are iid $N(0,1)$.

Comment: This is true -- but I could not think of an obvious way to use this fact in a proof.

Comment: Also, I have been able to verify my conjecture experimentally using this construction.